# Paginación incorrecta con una vista

Tags: python, django, formularios, paginación

Estoy trabajando en una vista con formulario, que muestra el formulario y el resultado de la consulta en la misma plantilla.  La cláusula de consulta a la tabla pertinente va bien y me devuelve los resultados correctos.

Utilizo una vista normal, donde lanzo el formulario, recojo la info del input text y pregunto a la base de datos.  Esta me devuelve un queryset que luego se muestra en principio, bien en la template.

Uso para paginar el módulo Paginator y me parte bien el queryset, cuando hay más del límite que he establecido, aparece en la template los botones de paginar.  Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema aparece cuando le doy al enlace de siguiente página o a una página cualquiera; momento en el cual, me muestra el formulario en blanco y un error en pantalla "This field is required.", el input text vacío y nada más.

Ya no sé por donde mirar, os pongo el código más importante:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import BuscarAlumno,BuscarCurso
from .models import *
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
...
def buscar_curso(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BuscarCurso(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('fullname')
            datos = MdlCourse.objects.filter(fullname__icontains=name)
            page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
            paginator = Paginator(datos, 20)           
            try:
                datos = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                datos = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                datos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            
            return render(request,'consultaCurso/busca_curso.html',{'form':form, 'datos': datos})
    else:
        form = BuscarCurso(request.POST)
    return render(request,'consultaCurso/busca_curso.html',{'form':form})
```

La plantilla es:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Resumen de cursos{%endblock title%}
{% block content %}
<h1>Buscar datos resumidos de un curso</h1>
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <form method="POST" class="post-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Fullname </th>
          <th scope="col">Shortname</th>
          <th scope="col">Fecha de creación</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for Curso in datos %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ Curso.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ Curso.fullname }}</td>
            <td>{{ Curso.shortname }}</td>
            <td>{{ Curso.timecreated }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>


<!--paginación-->
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mt-5">
  
          {% if datos.has_previous %}
              <li class="page-item">
                  <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ datos.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
              </li>
          {% endif %}
  
          {% for i in datos.paginator.page_range %}
  
              {% if i == datos.number %}
                  <li class="page-item active">
                      <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ i }}</a>
                  </li>
              {% else %}
                  <li class="page-item">
                      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                  </li>
              {% endif %}
              
          {% endfor %}
  
          {% if datos.has_next %}
              <li class="page-item">
                  <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ datos.next_page_number }}">next</a>
              </li>
          {% endif %}
  
    </ul>
  </nav>
<!--fin paginación-->
 

{% endblock content %}
```

Ya no sé cómo solucionar esta incidencia.